# What holds good?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

If the 1 ohm resistor is replaced by a 0.2 ohm resistor. what will be the current flowing through ? 
What actually determines it ? the OHM'S LAW or POWER CONSERVATION ?

[image: photo courtesy: http://www.blueraja.com/blog/194/do-transformers-obey-ohms-law]

Comment: Hi Vinayak, please take a moment to read this post about [Writing a good question title](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6413/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both holds true. If you use Ohm's law, you can easily see that $$i_1 R_1 = i_2 R_2$$.

So, $$10 \times 1 = i_2 \times 0.2$$ gives  $$i_2 = 50\,\mathrm{ampere}$$

Again by power conservation, $$V_{left} i_{left} = V_{right} i_{right}$$

And current in left loop will increase to be $i_{left} = 500\,\mathrm{ampere}$.

As you can see, here both Ohm's Law as well as power conservation holds true.

Comment: how does the current increase in the left coil ?

Comment: I don't see any restriction in this happening. You change the resistance and yet keep the potential difference of each coil same. Then the resistor i.e. the transformer draws more current from the source. That's it.